# Windows (XP+) Tool for letting others know what is happeing in the office (but not email, more like IM)

Tags: windows, software-rec, alert

I'm looking at how to notify others in a kind of twitter way, but a bit more obtrusive, to alert them to something that is about to happen, or did happen or even is happening.

e.g

> QA Website will be restarted in 2 mins

or

> Code cutoff for sprint 2.2.1 in 1 hour

or

> Trunk build broken

I like Growl for announcements, but is there a tool that can sit on everyone's desktop and send these announcements to all clients as well?

The reasoning behind it is that people know what is happening when it happens. Not "Oh, the QA environment is down. That's a bug"

Comment: Would be helpful to know what platform(s), i.e. Windows XP, Ubuntu, OS X...

Comment: just how obtrusive do you want it to be? big alert box that user needs to click to get on with work; small pop up that fades on it's on away? simple mass mail is also a way for announcements.

Comment: ah, that is true about the OS. I have been developing around mostly Visual Studio types so never had to mention. Answer updated

Comment: it needs to about obtrusive as the outlook "received mail" toaster effect, but not email as it needs to be a little more instant

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **windows 32 bit** and If you are speaking about IM in LAN then use  [ipmsg](http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en). You can choose all visible person in LAN and sent them a message simultaneously which will pop up in their respective machine

Comment: Probably should know what platform he is using before recommending windows 32 bit apps...

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: ipmsg looks promising.

Comment: ipmsg is what they use in my dad's office